# Replace a certain index of a string in python 3.0

Tags: python, string

I need to replace a character in a string but here is the catch, the string will be all underscores and I need to be able to replace the underscore that corresponds to the index of the word. For example:

```
underscore = '___'
word = 'cow'
guess = input('Input the your letter guess') #user inputs the letter o for example
if guess in word:
    underscore = underscore.replace('_',guess)
```

what i need to be fixed is that the underscore that gets replaced needs to be in the second place of the three underscores. I dont want `underscore = 'o__'` but rather `'_o_'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to exclude all other characters from `word`, and form a new string like this

```
def replacer(word, guess):
    return "".join('_' if char != guess else char for char in word)

assert(replacer("cow", "o") == "_o_")
```

This will work even if there are multiple occurrences of the guessed character

```
assert(replacer("bannana", "n") == "__nn_n_")
```

The `replacer` function, iterates the `word`, character by character and on each iteration, the current character will be in `char` variable. Then, we decide what should be filled in place of the current character, in the resulting string with

```
'_' if char != guess else char
```

This means that, if the current character is not equal to the guessed character, then use `_` otherwise use the character as it is. And finally all those characters are joined together with `"".join`.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you so much! I was clearly taking the wrong approach and trying to deal with a string of underscores while the proper way (that way you did it, if i understand correctly) is using the word and surrounding it with underscores

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are **immutable**. You can't change them. You can only redefine them.

An easy way to do this is to find the index of the relevant letter:

```
index = "cow".index("o")
```

and then to just take the rest that you need from your word using slice notation:

```
newword = word[:index] + yourletterhere + word[index+1:]
```

for example:

```
>>> "bananaphone".index("p")
6
>>> "bananaphone"[:6]
'banana'
>>> "bananaphone"[7:]
'hone'
>>> "bananaphone"[:6] + "x" + "bananaphone"[7:]
'bananaxhone'
```

Comment: I strings are immutable, then how come we can use replace on them?

Comment: Replace redefines the string. You are overwriting the old one with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Find the index position of second occurrence of '_'
i = underscore.find("_",underscore.find('_')+1)  

#Create a new string with the requirements
newstr = underscore[:i] + 'o' + underscore[i+1:]
print(newstr)  


>>> underscore = "___"
>>> i = underscore.find("_",underscore.find('_')+1)
>>> newstr = underscore[:i] + 'o' +underscore[i+1:]
>>> print(newstr)
_o_
```